# which jquery is best to use

Tags: jquery

I want to change a selected button (buttons = .answerBtns) to an unselected button if OptionDropId (drop down menu) option changes.

Below is jquery code for drop down menus

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var OptDrop = new Array();

    OptDrop.abc = ["",1,2];
    OptDrop.abcd = ["",1,2,3];
    OptDrop.abcde = ["",1,2,3,4];
    OptDrop.trueorfalse = [1];
    OptDrop.yesorno = [1];

    $("#optionDropId").change(function ()
    {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#numberDropId").html("");
        $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function (x, y)
        {
            $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
        });
     });
     $("#optionDropId").change();
});
```

Now what I want to know is which jquery feature is best to use to unselect a selected button if the dropdown option in OptionDropId changes.

Is it the remove attribute code below:

```
$(".answerBtns").bind('click', function(){
    $(".answerBtns").removeAttr("selected");;
    return false;
});
```

Or is it returning false for the answer buttons below:

```
 $(".answerBtns").bind('click', function(){
    $('.answerBtns').attr('selected', false);
    return false;
```

Which one is the best to use in my code?

to look at full code then click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qM9Hp/1/)

Comment: The selectors on your two options are different: `$("#optionDropId")` and `$('.answerBtns')`.  Is that meant to be like that or are they both supposed to be `$("#optionDropId")`?

Comment: I changed it so they are both .answerBtns, I hope that is correct, to remove attribute to the button if it is selected?

Comment: What do you mean the `selected` attribute on the button? Buttons don't have a `selected` attribute. `selected` is an attribute of a select option

Answer (score 1):

I would use `removeAttr` as it better represents what's actually happening (ie the `selected` attribute is being removed from the HTML)

Comment: can I ask where I suppose to put this in my jquery code, does it go after the change() or before the change? Also will that code work if include it in my code (.answerBtns is the class of all buttons and OptionDropId is the dropdown menu).

Comment: Put it immediately be before `$("#optionDropId").change();`

Comment: It's a little hard to know what will work, could you setup your scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link to it in the question

Comment: I posted it in jsfiddle which you can access from my question, the code posted works on my browser but may not be outputted correctly at jsfiddle, but don't worry hopefully the code I have put in is enough info to help you

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do, that example doesn't seem to do anything.